# Bootstrap 3 off canvas menu button visibility

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and trying to make a left hand menu which the user can toggle visible/hidden on any viewport size. Basically a menu that the user can choose to show/hide that works responsively.

The closest example I've found to what I want is this: https://codepen.io/assemany/pen/grJoyx

However one of the things I'd like to implement is a button where the user can toggle this menu to being visible/invisible **on any viewport size**. At the moment it's using Bootstrap's grid system and a media query which means the button to toggle the visility isn't shown on anything >768px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    background:#ecf0f1;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
      .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -40%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 40%;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 40%;
        margin-left: 12px;
  }
}
```

I found another example here https://codepen.io/daanvankerkom/pen/vZBRoM which has the button and effect I'm looking for. However, the menu on this seems to "overlap" the content rather than work in a responsive way. A few other examples I found don't seem to work responsively but simply display the menu over the top of the content, which isn't what I want.

Going back to the first Codepen example I tried to add the button which toggles the sidebar into the sidebar itself:

```
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-reorder"></i></a>
```

I removed the `.visible-xs` class so that the button would be visibile on any screen size.

This doesn't seem to work - the button itself doesn't work, even keeping the following js in place:

```
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
   $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
});
```

The menu only "disappears" when the viewport has been resized to <768px.

Can anyone give me guidance on whether this is even possible? One issue I've realised is that the left sidebar will always need to occupy a certain amount of width so that the button to toggle visibility will fit into it - not sure whether setting a `min-width:` on `#sidebar` is the way to go here?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to achieve your desired effect for that you have to remove media css  `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)` for show toggle effect on all the screen size but by removing media css you can see that your page gives horizontal scroll(not responsive) when you open sidebar so, for maintain responsive behavior of your  page you have to change some css as i done in my snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
footer {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/*
 * Off Canvas
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
.row-offcanvas {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  background:#ecf0f1;
}
.row-offcanvas-left #sidebar {
  display: none;
}
.row-offcanvas-left.active #sidebar {
  display: block;
}
  
#sidebar {
    padding:15px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">

                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.well -->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <br>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <a href="#" class="" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-reorder"></i></a>
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Bootstrap is a front-end framework that uses CSS and JavaScript to facilitate responsive Web design. Bootply is a playground for Bootstrap that enables developers and designers to test, prototype and create mockups using Bootstrap
                        friendly HTML, CSS and Javascript.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Bootply is a playground for Bootstrap that enables developers and designers to test, prototype and create mockups using Bootstrap friendly HTML, CSS and Javascript. Bootstrap is a front-end framework that uses CSS and JavaScript to
                        facilitate responsive Web design. </p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->

                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Bootstrap is a front-end framework that uses CSS and JavaScript to facilitate responsive Web design. Bootply is a playground for Bootstrap that enables developers and designers to test, prototype and create mockups using Bootstrap
                        friendly HTML, CSS and Javascript.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Bootstrap is a front-end framework that uses CSS and JavaScript to facilitate responsive Web design. Bootply is a playground for Bootstrap that enables developers and designers to test, prototype and create mockups using Bootstrap
                        friendly HTML, CSS and Javascript.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a></p>
                </div>
                <!--/span-->
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->


    </div>
    <!--/row-->

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>© Company 2013</p>
    </footer>

</div>
<!--/.container-->
```